# Is MinGW required to run C++ on Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am clearing space in my harddrive and MinGW is downloaded on to the Hardrive. I needed MinGW for the Atom Text Editor, which I am not using anymore. If I delete the MinGW application will C++ still work for Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: MSVC and MinGw are two completely independent applications.

Comment: What is MSVC?  j

Comment: Visual Studio does not use MinGW in any way.

Comment: @c0d3r "What is MSVC" - " Microsoft Visual Studio".

Comment: Ok, thank you. This helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio and MinGW are totally different application.
Microsoft Visual Studio is IDE and have its own compiler for C++, which is why you needed MinGW for Atom Text Editor since its an editor and you needed a compiler for it. 
So yeah, even if you delete the MinGW application C++ will still work for Visual Studio 2019.